# Counting using a pre-defined list

Tags: python, list, count

Im trying to count values in a huge list using a predefined list.

Predefined list of values to be counted: `p = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

huge list on which counting is to be done: `h = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c'.....]`

currently im using

```
count = []
for item in p:
   count.append(h.count(item))

Out: count = [1,0,2]
```

This method, however, is very slow if `h` is very large. Is there a fast pythonic way to do this? I can't use `collections Counter` as it wont return me 0s for the values which are present in `p` but not in `h`.

Comment: how about using dict, 
    p = {"a":0, "b":0, "c":0}; 
    for i in h:  
        if i in p: 
           p[i] += 1

Comment: @AnkushShah Indention, please.

Comment: @LutzHorn: seems indentation don't work in comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `Counter` anyway and then coerce `Counter` to behave like you want. In fact, `Counter` already prints 0 by default for any item that it never counted.

```
import collections

p = ['a', 'b', 'c']
h = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c']

c = collections.Counter(h)
print c

for i in p:
  print i, c[i]
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
a 1
b 0
c 2
```

Comment: or `[c[k] for k in p]` to match the OP's output

Answer (score 2):

Intialize a dictionary using the items of `p` as keys with 0 as value and then loop over `h` and check if the current item is in that dict, if yes, increment its value:

```
>>> p = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> h = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c']
>>> c = dict.fromkeys(p, 0)
>>> for x in h:
...     if x in c:
...         c[x] += 1
...         
>>> c
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 0}
# ...
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(*p)(c)
(1, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only loop once:

```
In [2]: h = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'c']

In [8]: p = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [9]: c = {x:0 for x in p}

In [10]: for x in h:
    if x in c:
        c[x] += 1
   ....:         

In [11]: c
Out[11]: {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}
```

Comment: You could actually define `p` as a set, so that the lookup `x in p` is O(1) instead of O(len(p)).

Comment: you can just lookup in the dict c, that would also be O(1). no need for set